Can't redirect to thank you page - Magento
I am working a Magento module. The user clicks on "Place order", an API call is made to an external API service, gets a unique ID, the Magento Order ID and the API unique ID are saved to a custom table, it constructs a url with the unique ID and redirects the user there. When the payment is complete, they get redirected back to Magento on a specific controller.
This is where I am having problems with. I need to now send them to the checkout/onepage/success thank you page but I can't understand what is preventing me from doing so.
I have a very basic redirection set up, that successfully redirects me to the cart page but when I try to redirect to the thank you page, it sends me back to the cart page. Here is my code:
<?php

namespace Namespace\Payment\Controller\Redirect;

use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
use Namespace\Payment\Helper\Data as Helper;
use Namespace\Payment\Model\MyOrder;

class Callback implements ActionInterface {

    protected $request;
    protected $response;
    protected $helper;
    protected $redirectFactory;
    protected MyOrder $myOrder;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        ResponseInterface $response,
        Helper $helper,
        MyOrder $myOrder,
        RedirectFactory $redirectFactory
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->myOrder= $myOrder;
        $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $orderId = '000000003';

        // This part does NOT work
        return $this->response->setRedirect(
            $this->helper->getSuccessUrl($orderId)
        )->sendResponse();

        // This part DOES work
        return $this->response->setRedirect(
            $this->helper->getCartUrl()
        )->sendResponse();
    }
}


The success url from the helper class returns https://whatever-ngrok-domain.app/checkout/onepage/success/?order_id=000000003
The cart url from the helper class returns https://whatever-ngrok-domain.app/checkout/cart/
Order '000000003' exists:

So why am I not able to get to the Magento thank you page and where can I find ANY kind of documentation to understand this better? I have not found anything online.
Edit: After digging more into the magento code I found this:
public function isValid()
    {
        if (!$this->checkoutSession->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->checkoutSession->getLastQuoteId() || !$this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderId()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

The first if is the one that fails because obviously I haven't done anything to make sure the session is filled with any data whatsoever, but the question still stands, because there is literally 0 information anywhere online or in the "documentation" for magento on what someone needs to do in order to go to the thank you page. How do I make sure the checkoutSession data are all filled up correctly when all I have is the $order itself?

Solved.
Apparently you need to inject the Magento\Checkout\Model\Session class and then call these on it:
        $this->checkoutSession->setLastSuccessQuoteId($magentoOrder->getQuoteId());
        $this->checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($magentoOrder->getQuoteId());
        $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($magentoOrder->getEntityId());

and then it let's you go to checkout.
I haven't found a single resource in the documentation that points to this, rather I needed to scour the arcane corners of the internet to gather this knowledge.
